# Como puxo elementos de uma outra página?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou elaborando um script que precisa remover elementos de um pagina da web e adicionar algumas informações de texto na minha. Preciso que me script pegue do IMDB a descrição de um anime, como eu posso fazer isso?

Exemplo: através de um link como esse `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0433740/?ref_=nv_sr_1`, eu conseguiria adicionar no meu html coisas como, a imagem principal, a descrição e a nota.

Comment: Só uma duvida, o imdb permite que isso seja feito?

Comment: Script para correr num browser? Basicamente, não dá. Os browser impedem normalmente XSS, a não ser que se utilize AJAX e Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: como @LS_dev e @diegofm comentarm, não é correto pegar informação assim do imdb e nem vai funcionar do browser de uma maneira simples. Porque você não usa a `api` do imdb? Ela permite você consultar e tratar os resultados, dai você pode mostrar no seu site da maneira que quiser, inclusive imagens. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api

Comment: Você pode fazer esse tratamento a nível de servidor. Um wget ou equivalente puxa a página, então vira edição de texto automatizada. Daí, após tratar o texto do jeito desejado, retorne para o browser a sua edição

Comment: Olha, não é interessante você fazer desse modo por 2 motivos
1 - O carregamento do seu site ficaria travado até você baixar o conteúdo do IMDB e reinseri-lo
2 - O conteúdo do IMDB não é estático, muda constantemente. Se eles mudarem uma tag, você pode atrapalhar todo seu site.
Como citado acima, ou você usa a API e pega o JSON. 
ou você roda um crawler de tempos em tempos que baixa pra um banco de dados as informações do imdb e a partir desse banco, você preenche seu site. Isso vai ser trabalhoso, mas funciona.

Answer (score 0):

O Imdb tem um [API](http://www.omdbapi.com/) e você pode pegar as informações de qualquer titulo por ela
API: http://www.omdbapi.com/

Função em Javascript para pegar as informações você pode fazer isso com PHP tbm

```
function GetImdb(titulo) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       var resutado = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       alert(resutado.Poster);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + titulo, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

GetImdb("Justice+League");
```

Comment: "This site is not endorsed by or affiliated with IMDb.com." in www.omdbapi.com